# Autoit ImageSearch and Windows 7 Unterminated String

Tags: autoit

I just found ImageSearch library, very cool!

But when I tried to test it out I got strange errors, the only one I can't seem to get around is:

> Line 46 (File "C:\...\ImageSearchDLL\ImageSearchTest.au3"):
>   U1A%a]A%01/4' Error: Unterminated String.

Thats the error but my script doesn't even have 46 lines so it must be in something its importing, here's the test script:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include "ImageSearchDLL.dll"
#include "ImageSearch.au3"

local $x, $y, $search

$search = _ImageSearch('search.bmp', 0, $x, $y, 0)
if $search = 1 then
    mousemove($x,$y)
EndIf

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "imagesearch", $x, 10)
```

its not line 46 in the imageSearch.au3 either.

So! my thinking is its a problem with the DLL.

I'm on windows 7, could it be that imagesearch.dll is not compatible with windows 7?

That would make me quite sad. Can someone help me? Perhaps there are newer alternatives I'm unaware of. Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/177190-imagesearch-gives-unterminated-string/

I found a "fixed" version that works with windows 7 here on the forums somewhere. attached is the file I found. I have no idea what was done to fix these unterminated string errors I kept getting but I must have been using a very old version or something. hope this helps others!

Answer (score 2):

You can not include .dll files on autoit. I don't know why you are using it.
The UDF calls it by itself.

The error must be on the version you are using. Just update it or look for a version more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your script using x64 or x86 compiler, depending on your system. Then executing it using yourscript.exe